# Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration$SecurityFilterChainConfigure

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration$SecurityFilterChainConfiguration

I have added all the necessary dependencies.I have got no compilation error but runtime error is happening.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your response. 
I have solved that issue .